# Compare-Object where item exists multiple times

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm using Compare-Object to compare the contents of two CSV (1 & 2) files which have been imported using Import-Csv. The current layout of CSV 1 is:

| title | quality |
| --- | --- |
| Movie A | 4K |
| Movie A | 1080p |
| Movie A | 720p |
| Movie B | 720p |

Layout of CSV 2 is:

| title | quality |
| --- | --- |
| Movie A | 4K |
| Movie B | 1080p |
| Movie C | 720p |
| Movie D | 720p |

In CSV 1, there is going to normally be the same movie a few times due to the differing qualities while in CSV 2, the movie should only ever exist once.

I've somewhat managed to achieve this as when using Compare-Object, it is checking the contents of the CSV and removing duplicates but only ONE duplicate item:

`Compare-Object $CSV1 $CSV2 -Property "title" -PassThru |  Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | Select-Object  "title", "quality"`

As a result, the output is now:

| title | quality |
| --- | --- |
| Movie A | 4K |
| Movie A | 720p |
| Movie B | 720p |

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this, any pointers would be useful and happy to answer questions.

Comment: I understand the contents you are comparing. What results are you wishing to achieve? I don't quite understand. Are you trying to make sure only one entry is in `$CSV2` from `$CSV1` ? Also, do you need to know if it is the highest quality, or only if it exists ? Do you want to know if the entry does not exist in `$CSV2` ?

Comment: @jrider sorry, never been the best at explaining stuff! At the minute, I'm not too concerned about the quality but I've put it in for the purpose of demonstrating how the CSV looks. CSV1 could have the same movie 3 times because the quality ranges from 4K to 720p but there should always be one entry in CSV2. But yes, I only want to see if does not exist in CSV2 but it does look to be working (to a degree) but not stripping out every entry because its already found one matching one.

Comment: You just want to know if  a `$CSV1` entry is in `$CSV2` ? And, only one time ?

Comment: @jrider yes, that's what I've been trying to do but because of the duplicates and alternate qualities it's proving to be a bit of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed example of what I think you are trying to accomplish.

```
$CSV1 = Import-CsV -Path ".\CSV1.csv"
$CSV2 = Import-CsV -Path ".\CSV2.csv"

#Group CSV by title to get any duplicate titles in CSV
$groupedCSV2 = $CSV2 | Group-Object Title


#iterate through CSV1 to make sure all titles are at least in CSV2 one time
#used to report the results
$report = foreach($movieEntry in $CSV1)
{
    #is movie Entry in CSV2 ?
    if($movieEntry.title -in $groupedCSV2.Name)
    {        
        $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Title = $movieEntry.title
            #how many are in csv2 ?
            Count = ($groupedCSV2| Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $movieEntry.title}).Count
            #quality in CSV2
            Quality = ($groupedCSV2 | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $movieEntry.title}).Group.quality -join ","
        }
        #add object to $report
        $object
        
    }
    #not in CSV 2
    else
    {        
        $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Title = $movieEntry.title
            #how many are in csv2 ?
            Count = 0
            Quality = $null
        }       
        #add object to $report
        $object
    }
}


#remove all duplicates from report
$report = $report | Select -Unique Title, Quality, Count

#### EXAMPLES ####
#to view all results call $report
$report
#to view all that are not in CSV2
$report | Where-Object {$_.count -eq 0}
#view all duplicates
$report | Where-Object {$_.count -gt 1}
#view all good entires
$repot | Where-Object {$_.count -eq 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know what titles in CSV1 aren't also in CSV2, irrespective of how often they appear in CSV1, and irrespective of their quality level:

```bash
Compare-Object ($CSV1.title | Select-Object -Unique) $CSV2.title -PassThru |
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
```

**[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-Unique` ensures that only *distinct* titles (no duplicates) are used in the comparison**; calling it for `$CSV2.title` too isn't necessary, given your premise that the titles are unique there.

The reason this is necessary is that **[`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) does *not* perform *set* comparison**; duplicates are matched individually against the other collection; thus, for instance, if the first among several duplicates is found in the other collection, but the others are not, these others are still reported as difference, as the following simplified example shows:

```bash
Compare-Object (1, 2, 1) (1 , 2)
```

Output:

```
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
          1 <=
```

That is, the *second* `1` value in the first collection was reported as a difference, because it had no counterpart in the second collection (after the *first* `1` was matched and eliminated from the comparison).